# Convenience script for renaming commit authors with git-filter-branch

Tags: git, bash, shell

For convenience, everything in this post is runnable as a Bash command.

I have the [following script](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/e9abc96db3efc9705add/54f7bbbd7b752dbf6830a9a451aa4db1ce442c59) based off of [GitHub's own](https://gist.github.com/octocat/0831f3fbd83ac4d46451):

```
cat <<EOF > git-unite
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Usage:
#
# git-unite "User Name" "new@email.com" \
#           "old1@email.com" \
#           "old2@email.com" \
#           ...

name="$1"
email="$2"

git config user.name "$name"
git config user.email "$email"

shift 2

for old_email in $*; do
echo "changing $old_email"
git filter-branch --force --env-filter '
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$(echo $old_email)" ]
then
  export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$(echo $name)"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$(echo $email)"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$(echo $old_email)" ]
then
  export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$(echo $name)"
  export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$(echo $email)"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
done
EOF
chmod u+x git-unite
```

Yet, when I run the script on a [test repository](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/dc896ccd9a272a126436) I've set up:

```
git clone https://gist.github.com/dc896ccd9a272a126436.git
cd dc896ccd9a272a126436
git-unite "Test Author" "new@email.com" "hehe2" "hehe"
```

nothing is changed.  What is the trouble?

> ```
> changing hehe2
> Rewrite be8d35aca918caaa86035ab8f8011d5ff6131939 (3/3)
> WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
> changing hehe
> Rewrite be8d35aca918caaa86035ab8f8011d5ff6131939 (3/3)
> WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged
> ```

---

[Using exports](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/e9abc96db3efc9705add/228720d83ef9d1161180b147884eb1f78779abac), the problem can be solved.  Is there any way to do this without exporting these variables?

Comment: If you print out `$email` from inside that filter-branch script does it have any value? (Also why `$(echo $name)` and `$(echo $email)` instead of just `$name` and `$email`?)

Comment: I tried it without the `echo` before, but it didn't work.  I believe this is because the command is run in a subshell of some sort (I'm not really privy to the terminology here) and these variables are lost.  I'd rather not export them as they have no meaning to anyone else.  After testing, it would seem that `$email` is empty regardless.

Comment: When I export, `name` is still empty and I get the empty ident error.

Comment: This [new version](https://gist.github.com/vermiculus/e9abc96db3efc9705add) of the script works fine now, but is there any way to do it without exporting?  I'm editing the original question post to reflect this question.

Comment: You only need to export `git_new_name` and `git_new_email` once, not once per-loop. And no, you need to export unless you do something like what @NoDataFound suggests with generating the script on the fly. But exporting isn't a problem because they don't escape your `git-unite.sh` script.

Comment: I did notice that after I updated the gist and fixed it locally.  That fix is now public, thanks.  And I was under the impression that `export` *exported* the variable's value to all other shells -- I suppose I should read the documentation more closely on that one.

Comment: It exports it for programs run by the current shell (it puts it into the process environment so it gets inherited). It does not affect any currently running programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to "inject" the `$name` and `$email`, you can export it *before* `git filter-branch`, or you can generate a bash script using `printf`.

**Notice:** the `$(echo $old_email)` does the same result than using `"$old_email"` and you could fork a process for nothing (well, if bash fork when you use builtins).

You can also use `printf`: the idea is to use the `%q` to dump the different variable in a quoted form (suitable for use in a bash script, or in eval). You also gain the advantage to split the script that effectively change the user name/email from the one that run the git command.

```
#action.bash:
declare -r _NEW_NAME="%q"
declare -r _NEW_EMAIL="%q"
declare -r _OLD_EMAIL="%q"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = %v ]
then
  export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="${_NEW_NAME}"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="${_NEW_EMAIL}"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "${_OLD_EMAIL}" ]
then
  export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="${_NEW_NAME}"
  export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="${_NEW_EMAIL}"
fi
```

And in your script:

```
git filter-branch --force --env-filter $(printf "$(<action.bash)" \
   "$name" "$email" "$old_email") --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

**Notice:**

1. `$(<foobar)` does the same work that `cat foobar` does. When you use `cat`, you might however except bash to create a sub-process instead of just reading the file `foobar`.
2. I truncated the `git filter-branch` (the `\`) line to avoid horizontal scrollbars.

This example is fine, but after thinking about it a little, I think you should not do it like that, but in a more bash way:

```
#action.bash:
declare -r _NEW_NAME="$1"
declare -r _NEW_EMAIL="$2"
declare -r _OLD_EMAIL="$3"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = %v ]
then
  export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="${_NEW_NAME}"
  export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="${_NEW_EMAIL}"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "${_OLD_EMAIL}" ]
then
  export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="${_NEW_NAME}"
  export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="${_NEW_EMAIL}"
fi
```

And instead:

```
git filter-branch --force --env-filter "$(printf 'action.bash "%q" "%q" "%q"' \
   "$name" "$email" "$old_email")" --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

That way, even if the script does nothing at all, it would still work if you needed it in a static way:

```
git filter-branch --force --env-filter 'action.bash name email old_email' \
  --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Comment: Yes, it's basically a quoting problem.  I don't have time to write up a full alternative answer but just note that `--env-filter '...$x'` has `$x` inside the single quotes, which keep it from being expanded.

Comment: Thanks! Question: this is the second time *today* that I've seen the `$(<file)` construction -- what does it actually do?

Comment: I updated my answer, again. It is basically the same, but with an example where you don't write a temporary bash file, but instead pass it the name/email/old_email as parameters.